# Django - AttributeError at /blog/cat1 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'views'

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

Would appreciate some help understanding whenever I try to fetch blog posts by category I am getting the following error: AttributeError at /blog/cat1 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'views'
'cat1' is name of category which i have created for test in django admin panel
[categories are displaying correctly with post but when try to fetch posts by category i am getting error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SiKRZ.png)

[pls check error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rHR9d.png)

Here's my models.py file

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.utils.timezone import now
from ckeditor_uploader.fields import RichTextUploadingField

# Create your models here.
class Post(models.Model):
    sno = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    content = RichTextUploadingField()
    thumbnail = models.ImageField(upload_to='featured_image/%Y/%m/%d/')
    categories = models.ManyToManyField('Category', related_name='posts')
    author = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    slug = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    views = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    timeStamp = models.DateTimeField(blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title + ' by ' + self.author
    
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "categories"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class BlogComment(models.Model):
    sno = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    comment = models.TextField()
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(default=now)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.comment[0:13] + "..." + "by " + self.user.username
```

Views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect, get_object_or_404
from blog.models import Post, BlogComment, Category
from django.contrib import messages
from blog.templatetags import extras
from django.core.paginator import Paginator, EmptyPage, PageNotAnInteger
import socket

# Create your views here.
def blogHome(request, tag_slug=None):
    allPosts = Post.objects.all().order_by("-timeStamp")
    # context = {'allPosts': allPosts}
    paginator = Paginator(allPosts, 5)
    page = request.GET.get('page')
    try:
        allPosts = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        allPosts = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        allPosts = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

    return render(request, 'blog/blogHome.html', {'allPosts': allPosts, page:'pages'})

def blogCategory(request, pk):
    category = get_object_or_404(Category, pk=pk)
    return render(request, "blog/blogCategory.html", {'category': category})

def blogPost(request, slug):
    post = Post.objects.filter(slug=slug).first()
    post.views = post.views+1
    post.save()

    # comments
    comments = BlogComment.objects.filter(post=post, parent=None)
    replies = BlogComment.objects.filter(post=post).exclude(parent=None)
    replyDict = {}
    for reply in replies:
        if reply.parent.sno not in replyDict.keys():
            replyDict[reply.parent.sno] = [reply]
        else:
            replyDict[reply.parent.sno].append(reply)

    context = {'post': post, 'comments': comments, 'user': request.user, 'replyDict': replyDict}
    return render(request, 'blog/blogPost.html', context)

def postComment(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        comment = request.POST.get('comment')
        user = request.user
        postSno = request.POST.get('postSno')
        post = Post.objects.get(sno=postSno)
        parentSno = request.POST.get('parentSno')

        # new comment
        if parentSno == "":
            comment = BlogComment(comment=comment, user=user, post=post)
            comment.save()
            messages.success(request, 'Your comment has been posted successfully')
            
        # replies
        else:
            parent = BlogComment.objects.get(sno=parentSno)
            comment = BlogComment(comment=comment, user=user, post=post, parent=parent)
            comment.save()
            messages.success(request, 'Your reply has been posted successfully')

    return redirect(f'/blog/{post.slug}')
```

Urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('postComment', views.postComment, name='postComment'),
    path('', views.blogHome, name='blogHome'),
    path('<str:slug>', views.blogPost, name='blogPost'),
    path('category/<category>/', views.blogCategory, name='blogCategory'),
]
```

Here's my blogCategory.html template(If i am rendering template incorrectly pls help me with it too)

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block title %} Categories {% endblock title %}
{% block blogactive %} active {% endblock blogactive %}
{% block body %}
<div class="container my-4">
    <h2>Related Articles:</h2>
    {% if posts == posts %}
    <p>No such Category</p>
    Your search did not match any documents.<br>
    Suggestions: <br>
    <ul>
        <li>Make sure that all words are spelled correctly.</li>
        <li>Try different keywords.</li>
        <li>Try more general keywords.</li>
        <li>Try fewer keywords.</li>
    </ul>

    {% endif %}

    {% for category in post.categories.all %}

        <div class="card mb-3">
            <div class="card-body">
                <div class="row g-0">
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="ratio ratio-16x9">
                        <!-- featured image --> 
                            <img src="{{ post.thumbnail.url }}" class="rounded featured-image-list" alt="{{post.title}}">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-7 ps-md-3 pt-3 pt-md-0 d-flex flex-column">
                            <h2 class="card-title h3">
                                <a href="{{ post.slug }}">{{ post.title }}</a>
                            </h2>
                            <div class="text-muted">
                                <small>
                                    Published {{ post.timeStamp }} by <strong>{{ post.author }}</strong>
                                </small>
                            </div>
                            <p class="card-text mb-auto py-2">{{ post.content|safe|striptags|truncatechars:300 }}</p>
                            <div>
                                <a href="{{ post.slug }}" class="btn btn-primary">Read more</a> | Categories:
                                {% for category in post.categories.all %}
                                    <a href="{{ category.name }}">
                                        {{ category.name }}
                                    </a>
                                {% endfor %}
                            </div>
                    
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


    {% endfor %}

</div>
{% endblock body %}
```

What I am Expecting: When anyone clicks on tag they should see blog posts of that category

Answer (score 0):

Raise erroe because **`post = Post.objects.filter(slug=slug).first()`** return None so...

Try with the below code snippet

```
post = Post.objects.filter(slug=slug).first()
if post is not None:
   # Perform actions with the retrieved post
   post.views = post.views + 1
   post.save()
```

also change in HTML

```html
<h2 class="card-title h3">
    <a href="{% url 'blogPost' slug=post.slug %}">{{ post.title }}</a>
</h2>

-------- and ------
<div>
    <a href="{% url 'blogPost' slug=post.slug %}" class="btn btn-primary">Read more</a> | Categories:
    {% for category in post.categories.all %}
        <a href="{{ category.name }}">
            {{ category.name }}
        </a>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

this error occurs when we don't have object on model, but we want to update some tables, In this code, you don't have any post object so its none, so it's better to check first if there is a post.view or not.

```
post = Post.objects.filter(slug=slug).first()
if post is not None:
    post.views += 1
    post.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in error message, you get an error in `views.py` in the second line of this function:

```py
def blogPost(request, slug):
    post = Post.objects.filter(slug=slug).first()
    post.views = post.views + 1  # Here
    post.save()
```

You get this kind of error, as your model couldn't find any record with given `slug` (in this case `cat1`). For that url (`blog/cat1`) you suppose to get a blog with `slug='cat1'`, but as you mentioned, `cat1` here is a `category`, not a `slug`.

You need to make some updates in `urls.py` and replace this:

```py
path('category/<category>/', views.blogCategory, name='blogCategory'),
```

with

```py
path('category/<str:category_name>/', views.blogCategory, name='blogCategory'),
```

In `models.py` make this change:

```py
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=50)
```

In `views.py`update the `blogCategory()` view with this:

```py
def blogCategory(request, category_name):
    category = category = get_object_or_404(Category, pk=category_name)
    return render(request, "blog/blogCategory.html", {'category': category})
```

Then in your template replace this:

```
{% for category in post.categories.all %}
    <a href="{{ category.name }}">
        {{ category.name }}
    </a>
{% endfor %}
```

with

```
{% for category in post.categories.all %}
    <a href="{% url 'blogCategory' category.name %}">
        {{ category.name }}
    </a>
{% endfor %}
```

This all should work, but I would recommend to look over official documentations to get more experience and advice for project architecture.

Here are some helpful links for:

[Django urls](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/topics/http/urls/)

[Django Forum: Best structure for urls](https://forum.djangoproject.com/t/how-best-to-structure-urls-in-django/9120)

[Django templates](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/topics/templates/)

Comment: Thank you so much! But I did some changes(Instead of categories i used django taggit model) in my code but to render that changes with my template I had to do extra googling and you know what my code is 90% same as yours, Can i ask you more? What changes will i have to do if i want to add subcategories within main category(I am going to add categories too) Again thank you..

Comment: I would recommend to start project from scratch with stet-by-step instructions (official documentation will be a good choice) to understand more relation between various components.